# Error installing libmaxminddb

Tags: makefile, maxmind, netbsd

I am trying to install the GEolite2 database on a netbsd server.  I can't get past the first make for libmaxmindb.  I get the following error;

```
make  all-recursive
Making all in src
Making all in bin
Making all in t
make: don't know how to make man/man1/*.1. Stop

make: stopped in /usr/local/maxmind/libmaxminddb-1.1.1
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/local/maxmind/libmaxminddb-1.1.1
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/local/maxmind/libmaxminddb-1.1.1
```

Hpw can I either fix this or get around it?

UPDATE:

I downloaded the tarball for 1.1.1 from github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb/releases/download/1.1.1/….

I noticed that the man directory has no Makefile in it and from what I could tell, maybe it should.

I am using NetBSD 6.0.1 and ran the steps in the Readme.

configure - ran normally 
make - failed as shown above. –

I also tried starting from a git clone - same result.

Comment: What file did you download? Those files should exist in the the distribution. Also please add more information about your setup and the exact steps you took.

Comment: I downloaded the tarball for 1.1.1 from https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb/releases/download/1.1.1/libmaxminddb-1.1.1.tar.gz.

I noticed that the man directory has no Makefile in it and from what I could tell, maybe it should.

I am using NetBSD 6.0.1 and ran the steps in the Readme.

configure - ran normally
make - failed as shown above.

Comment: I also tried starting from a git clone.  Same result.

Answer (score 1):

On BSD systems one should always use GNU Make with Makefiles generated by GNU Automake.

I see in `README.md` for the libmaxminddb repository on `github.com` that one is expected to run the `bootstrap` script after cloning the repo (which is quite normal, though more often the script is called `autogen`).

If you don't already have GNU Make and the GNU Autotools installed I recommend using [`pkgsrc`](http://pkgsrc.org/) to install them.

Comment: I've done that.  I went back and did a git clone instead of using the tarball.  bootstrap ran fine. configure ran fine.  Make failed in those man directories.

Comment: You keep saying "make" -- you need to try "gmake".

Comment: That did it!  I can't believe I've gone this long making that mistake

Comment: I have a new problem. This was step to installing mod_maxminddb for apache and it's now failing on ./configure.  I get;

checking maxminddb.h usability... no
checking maxminddb.h presence... no
checking for maxminddb.h... no
checking for MMDB_lib_version in -lmaxminddb... no

I ran ldconfig but got no output. I tried editing /etc/ld.so.conf but it hasn't helped.  Everything from libmaxminddb installed into /usr/local/.  Ideas?

Comment: Careful examination of the `config.log` file should reveal why it isn't finding the header or library.  `configure --help` may show how to specify the location of the header and library, if that's the problem (i.e. that it's not looking in /usr/local as expected).

Comment: This is an ELF system so ldconfig is irrelevant. I gave up and just symlinked usr/local/lib to /usr/lib. It's all installed now.